# Codeception: Cleaning test data from database

Tags: php, unit-testing, codeception

I have been writing some unit tests with Codeception and my database has been getting over run with the test data. While reading the documentation I found it says:

> Database will be cleaned and populated after each test

Does anybody know if there is anything in the yaml file or maybe something I need to put in the tear down method?

Here is my test:

```
use Codeception\Util\Stub;

class peopleAdminTest extends \Codeception\TestCase\Test
{
   /**
    * @var \CodeGuy
    */
    protected $codeGuy;

    /**
     * @var the model object
     */
    private $_model;

    /**
     * @var some mock data
     */
    private $_data = array( "people" => array( "title" => "Unit Test Data" ) );

    protected function _before()
    {
        $this->_model = new People_model();
    }

    public function test_instantiation()
    {
        $this->assertInstanceOf( 'people_model', $this->_model );
    }

    public function test_save()
    {
        $this->_model->save( $this->_data[ 'people' ] );
        $this->codeGuy->seeInDatabase( 'pegisis_people', array( 'title' => 'Unit Test Data' ) );
    }
}
```

Comment: Look here: http://codeception.com/docs/modules/Db

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I already have the queries to create my tables in my tests/_data/dump.sql file but I dont think anything happens because I am still left with data in my database

Answer (score 4):

Did you add populate: true and cleanup: true in unit.suite.yml?

Check vendor/codeception/src/Codeception/Module/Db.php. _after() or the teardown method in codeception does not cleanup the Db. The cleanup is done in _before() and then the sql is executed.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Adding populate: true and cleanup: true did seem to work although it doesnt clear the database the first time I run the test, only any time after. Also I dont have a codeception directory in my vender directory